# How to send '#' into ajax url using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

User enter value into input box and I need to run ajax.

```
var t_id = DN#2709;
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "enc_ref_id/"+t_id ,

    success: function(data){

    alert("No Record Found!");
    }
})
```

This is going like this

```
   "enc_ref_id/DN"
```

How can I send this "DN#2709" into ajax url???

Comment: I resolved like this

    var uri=("enc_ref_id/"+encodeURIComponent(t_id ));

Answer (score 4):

You can use `encodeURIComponent` to do this:

```
var t_id = DN#2709;
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: encodeURIComponent("enc_ref_id/"+t_id) ,
   success: function(data){
      alert("No Record Found!");
   }
})
```

The output should be `"enc_ref_id%2FDN%232709"`.

**OR**

Decode only the `t_id` part:

```
var t_id = DN#2709;
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: "enc_ref_id/" + encodeURIComponent(t_id),
   success: function(data){
      alert("No Record Found!");
   }
})
```

Also remember to **decode** it on the server side.